# Django Nested Json of Multiple Foreign Key Models

Tags: django, orm

I've 4 model that has relationship through FK.

```
class Journal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Volume(models.Model):
    journal = models.ForeignKey(Journal, related_name='volumes')
    number = models.IntegerField()

class Issue(models.Model):
    volume = models.ForeignKey(Volume, related_name='issues')
    number = models.IntegerField()

class Article(models.Model):
    issue = models.ForeignKey(Issue, related_name='articles')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

I need a JSON format like follow structure.

```
journal: [
    { name: 'Volume number goes here', type: 'folder',  id: 'F1',
        data: [
            { name: 'Issue number goes here', type: 'folder', id: 'F1F1',
                data: [
                    { name: 'Article name goes here>', type: 'item', id: 'F1F1I1' },
                    { name: 'Article name goes here>', type: 'item', id: 'F1F1I2' },
                    { name: 'Article name goes here>', type: 'item', id: 'F1F1I3' },
                ]},
            { name: 'Issue number goes here', type: 'folder', id: 'F1F2',
                data: [
                    { name: 'Article name goes here>', type: 'item', id: 'F1F2I1' },
                    { name: 'Article name goes here>', type: 'item', id: 'F1F2I2' },
                    { name: 'Article name goes here>', type: 'item', id: 'F1F2I3' },
                ]},
        ]
    },
    { name: 'Volume number goes here', type: 'folder',  id: 'F2',
        data: [
            { name: 'Issue number goes here', type: 'folder', id: 'F1F1',
                data: [
                    { name: 'Article name goes here>', type: 'item', id: 'F2F1I1' },
                    { name: 'Article name goes here>', type: 'item', id: 'F2F1I2' },
                    { name: 'Article name goes here>', type: 'item', id: 'F2F1I3' },
                ]},
            { name: 'Issue number goes here', type: 'folder', id: 'F1F2',
                data: [
                    { name: 'Article name goes here>', type: 'item', id: 'F2F2I1' },
                    { name: 'Article name goes here>', type: 'item', id: 'F2F2I2' },
                    { name: 'Article name goes here>', type: 'item', id: 'F2F2I3' },
                ]},
        ]
    }
],
```

I've tried several stuff but it will cause hundred of sql queries ( because of for loops )

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create that JSON file using exactly 4 queries. You just have to use `prefetch_related`.

Here is some proof of concept (for queries counter to work, you must have `DEBUG=True`):

```
from django.db import connection

journals = Journal.objects.all().prefetch_related('volumes', 'volumes__issues', 'volumes__issues__articles')

for journal in journals:
    print "%s" % journal.name
    for volume in journal.volumes.all():
        print "  %d" % volume.number
        for issue in volume.issues.all():
            print "    %d" % issue.number
            for article in issue.articles.all():
                print "      %s" % article.title

print len(connection.queries)
```

That will print simple tree of your objects and number of queries at the end, which will equal 4 (if there wasn't any queries done before in that connection). From that there is not far to create your JSON output.

In creating that exact JSON, [Django REST Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) can be helpful. Assuming that you have all your serializers done and nested, feeding `JournalSerializer` With above queryset, will create exactly 4 queries to database.

Answer (score 1):

Use [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) and [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related).  These methods are used in the Django ORM to do SQL JOINs, so you won't be duplicating queries.